# Getting Error: Content cannot be displayed: Subscript value 5 not valid. Must be between 0 and 4 When trying to create pageBlockTable from a List

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable

Here is my .cls

```
public List<List<String>> getObjectList() {
    //StructuralInfo_with_RoofSections acct;
    List<List<String>> arrList = new List<List<String>>();
    List<VS_Roof_Section__c> roof = [SELECT Name, Azimuth__c, MG_Azimuth_2__c, MG_Azimuth_3__c, Designed_Tilt__c ,Installed_On__c, Measured_Tilt__c, Pitch_Bonus__c, Roof_Section_Number__c, Roof_Type__c ,Shading_Coeffecient__c, MG_Tilt_2__c, Tilt__c, MG_Tilt_3__c
                                    FROM VS_Roof_Section__c
                                    WHERE Structural_Info__c=:struct.Id limit 14];
    /*catch(ListException e) {
        roof[0].Id = 'No values returned on SOQL Query';
    }*/


    for (VS_Roof_Section__c rs : roof) {
        List<String> objectList = new List<String>();

        objectList.add(String.valueOf(rs.Name));
        objectList.add(String.valueOf(rs.Azimuth__c));
        objectList.add(String.valueOf(rs.MG_Azimuth_2__c));
        objectList.add(String.valueOf(rs.MG_Azimuth_3__c));
        objectList.add(String.valueOf(rs.Designed_Tilt__c));
        objectList.add(String.valueOf(rs.Installed_On__c));
        objectList.add(String.valueOf(rs.Measured_Tilt__c));
        objectList.add(String.valueOf(rs.Pitch_Bonus__c));
        objectList.add(String.valueOf(rs.Roof_Section_Number__c));
        objectList.add(String.valueOf(rs.Roof_Type__c));
        objectList.add(String.valueOf(rs.Shading_Coeffecient__c));
        objectList.add(String.valueOf(rs.Tilt__c));
        objectList.add(String.valueOf(rs.MG_Tilt_2__c));
        objectList.add(String.valueOf(rs.MG_Tilt_3__c));

        arrList.add(objectList);
    }



    return arrList;
}
```

And Here is my .page:

```
    <apex:page standardController="VS_Structural_Info__c" extensions="StructuralInfo_with_RoofSections">
<apex:pageBlock title="Roof Sections" >
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!objectList}" var="detail">
            <apex:column headerValue="Roof Section ID" value="{!detail[0]}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Azimuth" value="{!detail[1]}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Azimuth 2" value="{!detail[2]}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Azimuth 3" value="{!detail[3]}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Designed Tilt" value="{!detail[4]}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Installed On" value="{!detail[5]}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Measured Tilt" value="{!detail[6]}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Pitch Bonus" value="{!detail[7]}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Roof Section Number" value="{!detail[8]}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Roof Type" value="{!detail[9]}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Shading Coefficient" value={!detail[10]}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Tilt" value="{!detail[11]}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Tilt 2" value="{!detail[12]}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Tilt 3" value="{!detail[13]}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable> 
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:page>
```

So I get the error spelled out in the title of this post...
If I comment out everything after detail[4] I only end up with

[image: pageBlockTable created from my code...]

Answer (score 1):

I have taken a look into your class and vf page. From the code it just looks like you are trying to get the values returned by the SOQL query in your VF page.

```
List<VS_Roof_Section__c> roof = [SELECT Id, Name, Azimuth__c, MG_Azimuth_2__c, MG_Azimuth_3__c, Designed_Tilt__c ,Installed_On__c, Measured_Tilt__c, Pitch_Bonus__c, Roof_Section_Number__c, Roof_Type__c ,Shading_Coeffecient__c, MG_Tilt_2__c, Tilt__c, MG_Tilt_3__c
                                FROM VS_Roof_Section__c
                                WHERE Structural_Info__c=:struct.Id limit 14];
```

Ideally you really don't need a `List<List<String>>` to display the values returned by the SOQL query. Because all you are trying to do is iterate over the returned value and essentially putting it back into the list again.

For instance. You should be able to achieve the table easily as follows.

## Apex Controller

```
public List<VS_Roof_Section__c> getObjectList() {

List<VS_Roof_Section__c> roof = [SELECT Id, Name, Azimuth__c, MG_Azimuth_2__c, MG_Azimuth_3__c, Designed_Tilt__c ,Installed_On__c, Measured_Tilt__c, Pitch_Bonus__c, Roof_Section_Number__c, Roof_Type__c ,Shading_Coeffecient__c, MG_Tilt_2__c, Tilt__c, MG_Tilt_3__c
                                    FROM VS_Roof_Section__c
                                    WHERE Structural_Info__c=:struct.Id limit 14];

return roof;


}
```

## Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page standardController="VS_Structural_Info__c" extensions="StructuralInfo_with_RoofSections">
<apex:pageBlock title="Roof Sections" >
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!objectList}" var="detail">
            <apex:column headerValue="Roof Section ID" value="{!detail.Id}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Azimuth" value="{!detail.Azimuth__c}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Azimuth 2" value="{!detail.MG_Azimuth_2__c}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Azimuth 3" value="{!detail.MG_Azimuth_3__c}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Designed Tilt" value="{!detail.Designed_Tilt__c}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Installed On" value="{!detail.Installed_On__c}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Measured Tilt" value="{!detail.Measured_Tilt__c}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Pitch Bonus" value="{!detail.Pitch_Bonus__c}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Roof Section Number" value="{!detail.Roof_Section_Number__c}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Roof Type" value="{!detail.Roof_Type__c}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Shading Coefficient" value={!detail.Shading_Coeffecient__c}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Tilt" value="{!detail.Tilt__c}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Tilt 2" value="{!detail.MG_Tilt_2__c}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Tilt 3" value="{!detail.MG_Tilt_3__c}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable> 
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:page>
```

## Reason

The Syntax "`<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!objectList}" var="detail">`" is more of a FOR EACH kind of an action. Where {!objectList} denotes a list of records and detail denotes a single instance of the object that is about to be iterated.

Kindly refer the following documents for more info.

Reference :

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_lists.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockTable.htm